# Text indent and manual width/height so its position fit into the background image [not in IE]

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have the typical image with logos and i am styling it as an `<ul>` when each `<ul li a>` will have text-indent to hide the anchor and manual width so it's position fits to the one in the footer background image,

works great in firefox and chrome but for some reason it looks horrible in Ie,

does anyone know why??

Posted an example of my problem http://jsfiddle.net/r5Pda/1/

It does not look exactly as in my project but i guess if we solve it here i will be able to,

any clue here?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is known IE bug: absolutely positioned floating element displays oddly sometimes. Try to fix it according to [these](http://www.brunildo.org/test/IE_raf3.html) experiments.

Comment: if we remove the absolute positining it looks pretty much the same: http://jsfiddle.net/r5Pda/2/